# How to authenticate Python client app for access to restricted Google Cloud function?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-cloud-functions

I've created a Google Cloud function and I would like to access it from a Python application I'm developing. I am able to access the function when there is no authentication required, but can't access the functions when I enable authentication.

Here is the service account key I'm using with stripped out info. The only role it is configured for is invoking cloud functions.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XYZ",
  "private_key_id": "XYZ",
  "private_key": "XYZ",
  "client_email": "XYZ",
  "client_id": "XYZ",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "XYZ"
}
```

It seems that authenticated requests require a token that's included in the requests `Authorization` header, but I don't understand where to acquire this token.

I've tried using the approach outlined [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#application-default-credentials) with environment variables and the default auth method, but this doesn't work. I assume this is because the service account key is different from an OAuth token. (I have created a new service account the Cloud Functions invoker permission and am using that service account key). I receive the following error:

`google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', '{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}')`

How do I generate this token to authenticate the request from my Python script? Or is the approach with the service account recommended, but something else is going wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet of the token?

Comment: @JossBaron I have a service account key but not a token (maybe they're the same thing?), and it matches the format shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) (as created with the console).

Comment: I assume you are using this?
from google.oauth2 import service_account

`target_audience = 'https://example.com'

creds = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(
        '/path/to/svc.json',
        target_audience=target_audience)`

Could be either the target_audience is not set right, or the permissions of your Service Account. What roles are assigned to that SA?

Comment: The role is set as a Cloud Function Invoker. I'm using option #1 (environment variable) listed here for authentication with the app default creds also mentioned: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working, though at time of writing [there is a bug in the documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/557#issuecomment-657677913) that threw me off.

Access protected Cloud Functions is possible by using the [IDTokenCredentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.IDTokenCredentials) class within the `google-auth` library:

```
credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file( 
         SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE, 
         target_audience="https://function/url/here",
 ) 

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.post(url)
```

I have my service account configured with the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role.

Comment: Hi @charliesneath, could you please accept your own answer? In this way, other community members can identify easily what was the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly in the roles you gave that service account. Service accounts are finicky and the roles / permissions do not always act the way you think they will in my experience. Start by making a Service Account that has full permissions (project owner). Use that service account in your script then begin limiting the permissions from there. It sounds like you will need at a minimum cloud function "admin". If that works try another level down. Cloud function "developer" etc.

Comment: I've noticed as much. Planning to create a test project and do exactly what you say since I've noticed the unexpected permissions required in some other parts of my projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, for instance, App Engine or even other Cloud Functions to connect to your Cloud Function, you can use this: [Function-to-function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function), the steps, basically are:

1. Grant the Cloud Functions Invoker.
2. In the calling function, you'll need to:
3. Create a Google-signed OAuth ID token with the audience (aud) set to the URL of the receiving function
4. Include the ID token in an Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the function.

   import requests

   ```
   //# TODO<developer>: set these values
   REGION = 'us-central1'
   PROJECT_ID = 'my-project'
   RECEIVING_FUNCTION = 'my-function'

   //# Constants for setting up metadata server request
   //# See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
   function_url = f'https://{REGION}-{PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/{RECEIVING_FUNCTION}'
   metadata_server_url = \
       'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='
   token_full_url = metadata_server_url + function_url
   token_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}


   def calling_function(request):
       //# Fetch the token
       token_response = requests.get(token_full_url, headers=token_headers)
       jwt = token_response.text

       //# Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
       function_headers = {'Authorization': f'bearer {jwt}'}
       function_response = requests.get(function_url, headers=function_headers)

       return function_response.text
   ```

I have tested this solution and works as expected.

If you're invoking a function from a compute instance that doesn't have access to compute metadata (e.g. your own server), you'll have to manually generate the proper token:

1. Self-sign a service account JWT with the target_audience claim set to the URL of the receiving function.
2. Exchange the self-signed JWT for a Google-signed ID token, which should have the aud claim set to the above URL.
3. Include the ID token in an Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the function.

The Cloud IAP docs have [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) to demonstrate this functionality. The part you could be interested in should be [this Authenticating from a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account)